# how to call local restful web service by ajax in android?

Tags: android, ajax, rest

I have restful web service. I want to get json from local restful by ajax in android(using webview).
this is code ajax in htmt file in app android

function Get(){
           $.ajax ({

```
            url: "[http://localhost:31132/api/Customer][1]",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",                
            success: function (data) {                    
                $('#d').append("sucess");
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {                  
                $('#d').append(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

This code run on browser very well. But it don't run in android. Emulator android use API level 10.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

[Quote](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html):

> By default, a WebView provides no browser-like widgets, does not enable JavaScript and web page errors are ignored.

Did you do:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**Update** If the web service does not run with the standard Android browser as-is, then it's no surprise that it doesn't run with a WebView. Although the question remains whether you configured the browser to identify itself as Android or "desktop". I haven't studied the video you posted in detail, but I got the impression that you wrote the web service yourself, using some (Microsoft?) framework. The key question is: How does this framework treat the Android requests, e.g. with respect to the User Agent (browser identification) which it sends. In general, the JavaScript support on Android is rather good and well-written AJAX libraries can deal with a variety of platforms. Therefore, the first thing I would

1. try is to set the UserAgend identification to something that fakes a desktop browser, and try again. If that doesn't work,
2. it would be valuable to figure which AJAX files the web service actually delivers to the client in the given configuration. And finally, if that doesn't work,
3. it would be wise to look at the error messages which the WebView issues.

Comment: @lqg 1) What do you mean by _local_ restful, where is the service running? 2) Does the service run with an Android browser? 3) Can you influence how the web service is implemented?

Comment: Restful is written by C#. When I press Ctrl+F5 restful run on my PC. I use ajax in android get json. you watch a video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bx374YJRmO0&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @lqg Question 2) from above remains unanswered: Does the service run with the regular Android browser?

Comment: 2) the service don't run with an Android browser :D

Comment: Thanks for your update. I called service of google, I use url = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=false. But I don't call my restful web service, I use url = http://localhost:31132/api/Customer (web service run on IIS in my laptop). I try to localhost = 10.0.2.2 , 127.0.0.1 or IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In web service URL try using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost.
localhost or 127.0.0.1 points to emulator / android device while 10.0.2.2 is a special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e. 127.0.0.1 on your development machine).

Try `http://10.0.2.2:31132` instead of `http://localhost:31132`

Comment: yes. I know that. I tried it. I don't know android support ajax jquery?. Do you know that?